# Sqlalchemy relation between classes in separate modules

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sorry for my english, but i'm try to explain :)

I have two models in separate modules:

**user.py** in ***lib.User module***:

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata=main_meta)

class User(Base):

... some fields ...

server = relationship("lib.Server.server.Server", uselist=False, back_populates="user")
```

**server.py** in ***lib.Server module***

```
Base = declarative_base(metadata=main_meta)

class Server(Base):

... some fields ...

user = relationship("lib.User.user.User", uselist=False, back_populates="server")
```

When I try to run code I've got an error:

```
Module 'User' has no mapped classes registered under the name 'server'
```

My question: how make a relationship between models/classes between separate modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `Base` instance part of a third module and import it to `user.py`/`server.py`, so that both `User` and `Server` inherit from the same instance of `declarative_base`. Then make sure that both modules have been imported into your application upon using your SQLAlchemy models.